# Rails omniauth Google - how to update profile data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, oauth

I'm using omniauth to authenticate a user via Google. When the user logs in via Google, I check if an account already exists with the same email (if it does, I reject sign in).

When I create the new User model, I give it the name, email, and the URL of the user's 'image'. I am not sure how to dynamically update the information in my database when the user changes their settings on Google, including the image_url when they change their profile image.

A good example of this scenario is this Stack Overflow; I signed up to SO with Google. Having changed my profile image (recently), I was surprised to find that my old Google image remains attached to my SO profile. Maybe it takes time for Google to change the old URL to represent the new image. I have noticed that *some* parts of Google use my new image, and other parts continue to use my old. Of course, this question doesn't have much to do with Google's profile image mechanism, I just think this is a perfect example.

#### My questions are:

- Should I want to do this, or should I instead provide the user the ability to change their details through my site, completely ignoring what happens to their Google profile?
- If I should do this, what is the best way? Checking on every login isn't ideal as the user might not log out for days or even weeks.
- Should I be storing the Google auth token? Currently, I'm not as I don't need to make any Google API calls -- I only use OAuth for the 'uid' to ensure it's the same account logging in (the email isn't used at all).

I don't think the answer will be "don't store user info, query Google instead", so I'm not really sure what best practice is in this scenario. A brief walkthrough on proper procedure would be very helpful.

Comment: include you code clearly explained

Comment: The code provides nothing of use. It is a best practice question, which could be asked for any language. The code I have works fine, but what I have so far doesn't relate at all to these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, oauth applications will use the endpoint `/me.json` as part of the login process: After the user is signed in, the app uses that fresh token to query their profile info right away and update data. In your case, I understand you ignore when email already exists. You should probably add a new step there, to update your local record if it already exists instead of purely ignoring it.

In other words, your app wont be automatically notified if users change their profile pictures. But you can always use their log in action to fetch the latest image (or use their token in a background job that runs every n periods of time using something like cron + whenever, assuming the oauth scope authorizes offline access)

Comment: I only reject login if the email already exists AND the user hasn't signed up using the same Google account. I could make it so that every time the user signs in, I update the information in the database.

Comment: Also: currently I'm NOT storing the Google token given from omniauth. Should I be storing that for validation or something? I don't use any Google APIs, so I don't need the token for that. I figured it's possible for Google to invalidate that token (maybe they logout of Google) so I'd like to be able to sign out the user if the token becomes invalid.

Comment: Yes,  you should store the tokens (both tokens to be exact). That way you can refresh the token when needed, and yes know if it is invalid to log the user out